# Return the value from Ruby block

Tags: ruby

I have a method

```
def method1(&block)
  #.............
  if condition == "yes"
    yield if block_given?
    {success: :true, value: **value returned from the block**}
  else        
    {is_success: :false, value: get_errors_array() }
  end
end
```

How do retrieve the value from `&block`? Should the `&block` use `return` keyword for that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `call`.

```
block.call
```

if `block` takes arguments, then give arguments:

```
block.call(whatever_arguments)
```

Comment: Thanks. How do I make &block require as an argument then?

Comment: I don't understand, why has the OP to change (the more idiomatic) `yield` with `block.call`?

Comment: @tokland It can go either way. Since the OP used the variable `block` in the argument,  I thought `call` should be used. But the fact that OP used `block_given?` is contradictory, and it suggests using `yield`. One way or the other but not both.

Comment: indeed, &block goes with block.call and no &block goes with block_given? and yield. Anyway, the problem seems to be that the OP believes yield is an statement.

Answer (score 6):

Nope, there shouldn't be a `return` in a block here. The "return" value of block is the value of last expression in it.

`value_returned = yield if block_given?`

Comment: If I want a &block to be given always, how do I achieve that?

Comment: Well, I guess you have to throw exception when `block_given?` returns false.

Comment: What if just call it as `value_returned = yield`

Comment: If calling it without checking and no block given, there will be an error.

Answer (score 3):

```
def method1
  fail("Needs block") unless block_given?
  if condition
    {success: true, value: yield}
  else        
    {success: false, value: get_errors_array}
  end
end
```

Notes and questions:

- If you use `yield` is not idiomatic to put `&block` in the method arguments. If you want to require the block write `fail("Need blocks") unless block_given?`. You can leave it out and then you'll get a "LocalJumpError: no block given", which is also ok.
- `yield` is an expression, not an statement.
- It's not idiomatic to write `method()`.
- You need a default value to be used when no block is given (unless you fail before, of course).
- You used different keys `success` and `is_success`, why?
- You used `:true` and `:false` instead of real booleans, why?

Comment: the expression value_returned = yield will fail anyway if block not given. I need the block to be given always, that's why I don't a default value.

Answer (score -1):

The & prefix operator will allow a method to capture a passed block as a
named parameter.

```
def wrap &b
     print "dog barks: "
     3.times(&b)
     print "\t"
end
wrap { print "Wow! " }  # Wow!  Wow!  wow!
```